# Finding expected value of $X^2$

Tags: probability, statistics

The question is:

$X$ is a random variable, and $f(x) = (x-1)/2$ for $1 \le x \le 3$

Find $\Bbb E (X^2)$

Here's my solution:
\begin{align}
\Bbb P(1)&= 0/2= 0 \\
\Bbb P(2)&= 1/2  \\
\Bbb P(3)&= 2/2= 1 \\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\Bbb E(X^2) =
& 1^2 \Bbb P(1) + 2^2 \Bbb P(2) + 3^2 \Bbb P(3)
\\
 =
& 1 \cdot 0 + 4 \cdot 1/2 + 9 \cdot 1 
\\
=
&
11
\end{align}
This is my solution, but it is wrong. I need help in understanding where my mistake is.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: $X$ apparently is a continuous random variable, not a discrete one. You need to calculate $\int_1^3 x^2f(x)\,dx$.

Comment: To emphasise David Mitra's point, if $f(2)= \frac12$ and $f(3)=1$, then these are not probabilities.  However $\int_1^3 \frac{x-1}{2}dx =1$ , so you should interpret $f(x)$ as the probability density function of a continuous random variable

Comment: Also if $1 \le X \le 3$ then as a basic check you should have $1 \le E[X^2] \le 9$

Comment: Or, note the sum of your "probabilities" exceeds $1$. So whatever $f$ is, it certainly is not the the probability mass function of an rv taking the values $1$, $2$, and $3$.

Comment: The point is the distribution of this ramdom variable is continuous but not discrete. What you have done is assumed X is discrete only taking on the integers between 1 and 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My mistake was confusing f for a probability mass function, rather than a (continuous) probability distribution function.

To find the expected value of a continuous function, we use integration.

Therefore, to find $$E(X^2)$$ we take the integral $$∫_1^3x^2f(x)dx$$ which I calculated to be 17/3

Thanks to everyone that commented!